# How to deploy a Jersey REST server to Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, jersey, jetty, grizzly

The "getting started" example for Jersey uses Grizzly, so we went with that.  This allowed us to configure authentication in a fairly straightforward manner, thusly:

```
private static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/rest/";

// com.ourapp.AuthFilter is a javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext
final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig(com.ourapp.AuthFilter.class).packages("com.ourapp");

// create and start a new instance of grizzly http server
// exposing the Jersey application at BASE_URI
final HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), rc);
```

All of this works locally, which gave us great hope.

Sadly, when we went to deploy all this to Heroku, we ran into some major issues with `BASE_URI`.  We tried a wide assortment of URIs, only to be met with runtime exceptions from Heroku on startup, such as:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Failed to start Grizzly HTTP server: Permission denied
```

and

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Failed to start Grizzly HTTP server: Cannot assign requested address
```

Finally, we decided to give up on Grizzly and try the Jetty solution which is given [here](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/getting-started.html#heroku-webapp) by the Jersey docs.

Amazingly, the Maven archetype that is provided in the docs simply fails to compile, straight out of the box.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-grizzly2 \
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DinteractiveMode=false \
-DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=simple-service -Dpackage=com.example \
-DarchetypeVersion=2.28
```

Specifically:

```
    root.setContextPath("/");
    root.setResourceBase(webappDirLocation);
    server.setHandler(root);
```

are totally undefined, and

```
    server.start();
```

requires an argument of type `LifeCycle`.

So, can somebody please help me to get Grizzly to work on Heroku? Failing that, can anybody tell me what is the correct config for a Jetty app, and how to get a filter of type `javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext` to do its job with Jetty?

Answer (score 1):

Many hours, several dozen random combinations of various things, and large chunks of hair later.......

```
    final String port = System.getenv("PORT");
    final String baseUri = "http://0.0.0.0:" + port;
    final HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(baseUri), rc);
```

and, in Procfile:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.ourapp.Main
```

It turns our Heroku assigns a random port number to the app at startup, which must be passed on to Grizzly like this.  Oh, and that 0.0.0.0 thing is just plain undocumented, it seems.